# Is there a concept of viewcontroller containment in NSViewController

Tags: macos

In iOS, you have a concept of View Containment, is there such things in OSX?

Basically I want to create multiple nsviewcontroller each managing a specific view. I'd have a MasterViewController with a menu on the left (like ITunes), each time the user click on an item on the left, it would load the correct nsviewcontroller to display it's view.

Any tips to achieve what I need is appreciated

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

As of OSX 10.10 there is, watch [Storyboards and Controllers on OS X](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2014/).

---

Comment.

NSViewController did basically nothing (other that load NIBs) for years, I'm glad to see that it finally got from attention. Certain people in the Cocoa crowd here have a snotty attitude about the view controller programming style; I've asked questions like this before and had the "are you a iOS newbie coming to Cocoa" response. That's something that I never understood, it's a great model for containment, and reuse.

Answer (score 0):

The main difference between OS X and iOS is that on an iOS device you have only one "window". On OS X there are desktops that can contain many windows that you can view and interact with at the same time.

In general, it sounds like you are trying to create an NSWindow that contains a single-column NSTableView for your list of choices on the left, and some other view that will display the detail of the selection on the right. It's common to place these within a vertical NSSplitView so the user can adjust their relative widths, but they could also stand on their own, as two separate subviews within the window's main view.

You typically use an NSArrayController to manage the list contents and track which particular item is selected. For your detail view on the right, you would use a single NSView with NSControl subviews that display values bound to the array controller's selected object.

If the data structure varies among your objects, swap in or show/hide various subviews as needed for the different types of data the particular selected object represents. You can use the "Conditionally Sets Hidden" binding option to automatically hide controls for which there is no applicable keyed value.

Alternatively, if there's a fixed number of objects in your list and their structures are all quite different from one another, then you may wish to use a tabless NSTabView that has a separate tab with its own custom view for each of your objects. Observe when the selection changes in your list, and select the appropriate tab accordingly.